# Regaining aether from infrastructure

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

I was looking for some information about what size infrastructure usually is and how much Aether it produces and how much a demon can regain by attaching to it.

The core rule book lists types of infrastructure, it mentions that a demon can regain aether and the dice penalty for actions while doing it. But nothing about the actual amount of aether one can regain.